# Enforce generic type parameter to be enum

Tags: typescript

This is what I want to achieve:

```
// first.ts
export enum First {
  One,
  Two,
  Three
}
```

```
// second.ts
export enum Second {
  One,
  Two,
  Three
}
```

```
// factory.ts

// for those who don't know, Record is just an object. key value pairs
type NotWorkingType<T> = Record<T , string>;
    

// I can't get either of these objects working. 
// What's an important detail here is that First and Second enums are external, and at any time a "Third" can be created and should just work.

const testObject: NotWorkingType<First> = {
  [First.One]: 'first',
  [First.Two]: 'second',
  [First.Three]: 'third',
}

const testObject: NotWorkingType<Second> = {
  [First.One]: 'first',
  [First.Two]: 'second',
  [First.Three]: 'third',
}
```

Currently, the problem occurs here:

```
// Type 'T' does not satisfy the constraint 'string | number | symbol'.
// Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'symbol'.(2344)
//                              |
//                              v
type NotWorkingType<T> = Record<T , string>;
```

I've tried to use `k in keyof typeof T` like this as well:

```
type NotWorkingOtherType<T> = {
  // 'T' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.(2693)
  //                 |
  //                 v
  [k in keyof typeof T]: string;
}
```

It seems like no matter which combination I use with generic parameters, it won't work with enums.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

TS is trying to tell you that the `Key` in `Record<Key, Value>` has to be either `string`, `number`, or `symbol`. That's because JS object property names can only be one of those types (and under the hood `number`s are turned to `string`s). Thus you'll need to promise (using the `extends` keyword) that the `T` in `type NotWorkingType<T> = Record<T, string>` can be assigned to the union `string | number | symbol`. You're using plain `enums`, and their member values are assignable to `number`:

```js
export enum First {
  One,   // First.One === 0
  Two,   // First.Two === 1
  Three  // First.Three === 2
};

type WorkingType<T extends number> = Record<T, string>;

const testObject: WorkingType<First> = {
  [First.One /* === 0 */]: "first",
  [First.Two /* === 1 */]: "second",
  [First.Three /* === 2 */]: "third",
};
```